# I can't send file to django server through angular and error says: The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form

Tags: python, django, angular, post

my code is like this and I send data through httpClient and it returns
[error on upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DRDR.png)
my angular version is 13
and django version is 4
and I'm using django rest framework for restApi
**ng component**

```
  const data={
    "image_url":this.imgFile,
    "caption": this.caption,
    'author':1
  };
  console.log(data);
  this.service.createPost(data).subscribe(res=>console.warn(res));
}
  onFileChanged(event:any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    if(!this. file) return
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);

    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imgFile = reader.result as string;

    };
  }
```

**django model**

```
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    is_liked = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
            return (self.caption)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption + ' | ' + str(self.likes)
```

**django view**

```
    def get(self, req):
        data = Post.objects.all()
        serialized = PostSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**django Serializer**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # image_url = ThumbnailerSerializer(alias='avatar')
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component.ts file

```
onFileChanged(event:any) {
const reader = new FileReader();
this.file = event.target.files[0];
this.form.patchValue({
  image: this.file
})
if(!this. file) return
reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);

reader.onload = () => {
  this.imgFile = reader.result as string;

};


onSubmit(){
  this.service.addRecord(
    this.signUpForm.value.likes,
    ...
    this.signUpForm.value.image,
  )
}
```

in your service.ts file

```
addRecord(
email: string,
...
image: File): Observable<any>{
let formData: any = new FormData();
formData.append("email", email)
...
formData.append("image", image)
return this.http.post<any>(this.APIUrl + "/post/",formData)
```

}